# Probability, exponential distribution

Tags: probability

The time until the failure of a hard-disk component is exponential distributed with a mean of $400$ days.

a. What is the probability that a hard-disk component will fail within $200$ days?

b. The hard-disk component manufacturer wants to claims that $95%$ of their components last more than $x$ days before failure. Find value of $x$ such that this statement is true.  State your answer to at least $2$ decimal places.

For part a I got probability of $0.5$.

For part b, $x =368$.

Please correct me if its wrong, thanks.

Comment: If you have answers then tell us how you got them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ be the time before failure. From the information we were given, the density function of $X$ is
$$\frac{1}{400}e^{-x/400}$$
(for $x\gt 0$).

For $w\ge 0$, the probability that $X\le w$ is
$$\int_0^w \frac{1}{400}e^{-x/400}\,dx.$$
Integrate. We get
$$\Pr(X\le w)=1-e^{-w/400}.$$
For your first problem, set $w=200$.

We leave it to you to use the machinery above to solve the second problem.

Comment: You are welcome. Once you solve the second problem, if you wish I can verify whether you got the right number.

Comment: what i got is 1198.29 , feels off , what i did , 95% = 0.95
from the formula, Pr(X less than equal to w) = 1-e ( -w/400)
where 0.95 = 1 - e (-w / 400) , 0.05 = -e (-w/ 400) , ln 0.05 = -(-w/400) , 400 ln 0.05 = w  ,  where W = 1198.29 days

Comment: That is correct. Only $5\%$ of hard disks will fail before then.  You may feel it is on the high side, it takes a while to get good intuition about the exponential distribution.

Comment: wow i didnt expect to get it right , i wasnt able to find this formula in my applied statistic course notes , just only  P(X less than equal to X1) = 1 - e (-lambda x X1) , expected value : 1 / lambda  and Variance = 1/ lambda^2 , it doesnt mention any integral methods , thats why im confuse on it.

Comment: I showed how to find $\Pr(X\le w)$ using the density function. It looks as if your book just supplies "canned" formulas, maybe because it is directed to students with little background in mathematics.  But certainly you could have used the canned formula to solve the problem. It looks as if you are reasonably comfortable with the algebra.

Comment: yeah I kinda notice that, so lambda in exponential distribution is also part of the mean ? which for this question was 400 so its lambda , 

reasonable comfortable with boolean algebra? not really , im really weak at probability so need more feedbacks and understanding on this topic

Comment: The parameter $\lambda$ is when density function is given as $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. It turns out that the mean is then $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. So if the mean is $400$, then $\lambda=\frac{1}{400}$.

Comment: Thanks , got a bit of understanding